# Replacing by using sed wit regexp

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Need to replace string in a file with regular expression.
My regexp is `api.(dev[0-9]+\.)?side.com` and I am using it with call:

```
sed "s/api.(dev[0-9]+\.)?side.com/$SERVER_HOST_VALUE/g"
```

But it didn't found any strings like "api.side.com" or "api.dev02.side.com". Regular expression worked for me and not worked only with "sed" command.

So how to use current regexp properly with `sed`?

Comment: Use `sed -r`, for regexp-extended. Otherwise, escape everything: `sed "s/api.\(dev[0-9]\+\.\)\?side.com/$SERVER_HOST_VALUE/g" file`

Comment: What do you mean by _My regexp is `api.(dev[0-9]+\.)?parkme.com`_?

Comment: If the regexp is `api.(dev[0-9]+\.)?parkme.com`, why are you using `api.(dev[0-9]+\.)?side.com` in the command? `parkme` != `side`.

Comment: @Barmar Sory, my fault. Edited

Comment: @fedorqui -r option helps me. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there are many dialects of regex, and the `sed` default regex is simpler than most other dialects.  You need to learn the regexes supported by your tools of choice, or how to make your tools of choice use the regex dialect you want (where that is an option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @fedorqui's and @hwnd's recommendation, use the [`-r` option](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sed%20-r%20-e):

```
sed -re "s/api.(dev[0-9]+\.)?side.com/$SERVER_HOST_VALUE/g"
```

Note: If you use single quotes instead of double quotes, the variable `$SERVER_HOST_VALUE` won't be expanded.

### Test

```bash
SERVER_HOST_VALUE="AWESOME"
tests=( "api.side.com" "api.dev05.side.com" )
for t in "${tests[@]}"; do 
    echo "$t" | sed -re "s/api.(dev[0-9]+\.)?side.com/$SERVER_HOST_VALUE/g"
done
```

### Output

Note how the matches are replaced by `$SERVER_HOST_VALUE`:

```
AWESOME
AWESOME
```

Comment: +1 for the link, I wasn't aware of this explainshell tool. Also, it would be good if you indicate the output in your test.

Comment: @Édouard Lopez -r option helps me. Thanks!